# How to verify some behavior after a future has completed, with mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I want to verify an action is done after a future is completed, with mockito. But how should I proceed?

This is the test I tried to execute:

```
test('action should be called after future is complete',
      () {
    //GIVEN
    // ...

    //WHEN
    functionBeingTested();

    //THEN
    verify(mockedDependency.futureReturningFunction());
    verify(mockedDependency.action());
  });
```

And these are the codes that pass the test, but only one of them should pass:

```
// Correct code
functionBeingTested() {
  mockedDependency.futureReturningFunction().then(() {
    // ...
  }).whenComplete(() {
    mockedDependency.action();
  });
}

// Wrong code that also passes the test
functionBeingTested() {
  mockedDependency.futureReturningFunction().then(() {
    // ...
  });
  mockedDependency.action();
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm aware my test is not quite right. Please help me correct it.

What I really want is to verify if `mockedDependency.action()` is called after `mockedDependency.futureReturningFunction()` completes. How can I do that?

Comment: In your test, you are verifying that `mockedDependency.futureReturningFunction()` AND `mockedDependency.action()` are called. It is indeed the case in both codes you are testing. Why  do you think it shouldn't pass the test ?

Comment: @Muldec Yes, you are right. I updated the question, please take a look :)